# Problem with designing a site content filter

Tags: javascript

I decided to make a filter on my site, but there was a problem.
When some filter becomes active (for example, *'by popularity'*), on the main page instead of '*sorting*' there should be '*sorting by popularity*' when you click on the '*apply*' button.

I tried to do it: I tried to make a condition where if `filtr__img.style.display = 'block'`, then add '*by popularity*' to '*sorting*'

If you can somehow optimize the code itself and explain your solution, I will be very grateful.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const filtr__end = document.querySelector('#filtr__end')
const filtr__popup = document.querySelector('#filtr__popup')
const filtr__inner = document.querySelector('#popup__inner')
const $open__filtr = document.querySelector('#open__filtr')
const btn__filtr = document.querySelector('#btn__filtr')

btn__filtr.onclick = function() {
  filtr__popup.style.display = 'none'
  filtr__inner.style.display = 'none'
  body.style.overflow = 'auto'
};
$open__filtr.onclick = function() {
  filtr__popup.style.display = 'block'
  filtr__inner.style.display = 'block'
  body.style.overflow = 'hidden'
};
filtr__end.onclick = function() {
  filtr__popup.style.display = 'none'
  filtr__inner.style.display = 'none'
  body.style.overflow = 'auto'
};

const filtr__el1 = document.querySelector('#filtr__el1')
const filtr__img1 = document.querySelector('#filtr__img1')
const filtr__el2 = document.querySelector('#filtr__el2')
const filtr__img2 = document.querySelector('#filtr__img2')
const filtr__el3 = document.querySelector('#filtr__el3')
const filtr__img3 = document.querySelector('#filtr__img3')
const filtr__el4 = document.querySelector('#filtr__el4')
const filtr__img4 = document.querySelector('#filtr__img4')
const filtr__el5 = document.querySelector('#filtr__el5')
const filtr__img5 = document.querySelector('#filtr__img5')

filtr__el1.onclick = function() {
  filtr__img1.style.display = 'block'
  filtr__img2.style.display = 'none'
  filtr__img3.style.display = 'none'
  filtr__img4.style.display = 'none'
  filtr__img5.style.display = 'none'
};
filtr__el2.onclick = function() {
  filtr__img2.style.display = 'block'
  filtr__img1.style.display = 'none'
  filtr__img3.style.display = 'none'
  filtr__img4.style.display = 'none'
  filtr__img5.style.display = 'none'
};
filtr__el3.onclick = function() {
  filtr__img3.style.display = 'block'
  filtr__img1.style.display = 'none'
  filtr__img2.style.display = 'none'
  filtr__img4.style.display = 'none'
  filtr__img5.style.display = 'none'
};
filtr__el4.onclick = function() {
  filtr__img4.style.display = 'block'
  filtr__img1.style.display = 'none'
  filtr__img2.style.display = 'none'
  filtr__img3.style.display = 'none'
  filtr__img5.style.display = 'none'
};
filtr__el5.onclick = function() {
  filtr__img5.style.display = 'block'
  filtr__img1.style.display = 'none'
  filtr__img2.style.display = 'none'
  filtr__img3.style.display = 'none'
  filtr__img4.style.display = 'none'
};
```

```css
.business__content {
  max-width: 83%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 17%;
  background-image: url(./5594016.jpg);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.link__business {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.business__inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.business__el {
  width: 500px;
  height: 450px;
  border: solid 1px rgb(179, 179, 179);
  left: 20%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: 4%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  transition: .2s linear;
}

.business__el:hover {
  border: solid 1px rgb(94, 94, 254);
}

.img__business__el {
  width: 450px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.business__info {
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 550;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.buy__main {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.discount__main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.discount {
  font-size: 14px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.-price {
  color: rgb(47, 47, 225);
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-top: 0.5px;
}

.price {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin: 0;
}

.buy__webmarket {
  border: solid 1.5px rgb(94, 94, 254);
  color: rgb(94, 94, 254);
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0px 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 550;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: .2s linear;
  max-height: 40px;
  min-height: 40px;
}

.buy__webmarket:hover {
  background-color: rgb(94, 94, 254);
  color: #fff;
}

.discount__photo {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin-left: 4px;
}

.logistic {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-left: 25px;
  align-items: flex-end;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.img__logistic {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.logistic__text {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

.NextRow {
  margin-top: 4%;
}

.main__business {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
}

.main__passive {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-right: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.main__passive:hover {
  color: red;
}

.main__active {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-right: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: red;
  opacity: 0.8;
  display: none;
}

.title__business {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 550;
  opacity: 0.8;
  padding-top: 4%;
}

.filtr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

.filtr__text {
  margin-right: 12px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.filtr__text:hover {
  color: #4e4e4e;
}

.filt__img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 4.2%;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.filtr__popup {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2000;
  background-color: #000000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  transition: .2s linear;
}

.popup__content {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.popup__filtr__inner {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 420px;
  width: 800px;
  bottom: 3%;
  z-index: 3000;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.filtr__popup__title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1.5%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.filtr__el {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: .1s linear;
}

.filtr__el:hover {
  background-color: #bdbdbd;
}

.filtr__el__link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.filtr__el__text {
  color: black;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

.filter__el__img {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-right: 5%;
  display: none;
}

.dodo {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.btn__filtr {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgb(52, 152, 230);
  padding: 10px 23px;
  border: transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  transition: .1s linear;
}

.btn__filtr:hover {
  background-color: rgb(50, 132, 186);
}

.end__filtr {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #666666;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1%;
  right: 2%;
}

.end__filtr:hover {
  color: #383838;
}
```

```html
<div id="open__filtr" class="filtr">
  <img class="filt__img" src="./img/equalizer_filter_filtering_mixer_sorting_icon_123287.png" alt="">
  <div class="filtr__text">
    Sorting</div>
</div>
<div id="filtr__popup" class="filtr__popup">
  <div class="popup__content">
    <div id="popup__inner" class="popup__filtr__inner">
      <div class="filtr__popup__title">Sorting</div>
      <button id="filtr__end" class="end__filtr">&times;</button>
      <a id="filtr__el1" class="filtr__el__link" href="#">
        <div id="filtr__el" class="filtr__el">
          <div class="filtr__el__text">By popularity</div>
          <img id="filtr__img1" class="filter__el__img" src="./img/BJxRQ2SIARk.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </a>
      <a id="filtr__el2" class="filtr__el__link" href="#">
        <div id="filtr__el" class="filtr__el">
          <div class="filtr__el__text">By novelty</div>
          <img id="filtr__img2" class="filter__el__img" src="./img/BJxRQ2SIARk.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </a>
      <a id="filtr__el3" class="filtr__el__link" href="#">
        <div id="filtr__el" class="filtr__el">
          <div class="filtr__el__text">By presence</div>
          <img id="filtr__img3" class="filter__el__img" src="./img/BJxRQ2SIARk.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </a>
      <a id="filtr__el4" class="filtr__el__link" href="#">
        <div id="filtr__el" class="filtr__el">
          <div class="filtr__el__text">By ascending price</div>
          <img id="filtr__img4" class="filter__el__img" src="./img/BJxRQ2SIARk.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </a>
      <a id="filtr__el5" class="filtr__el__link" href="#">
        <div id="filtr__el" class="filtr__el">
          <div class="filtr__el__text">
            By price reduction</div>
          <img id="filtr__img5" class="filter__el__img" src="./img/BJxRQ2SIARk.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </a>
      <div class="dodo">
        <button id="btn__filtr" class="btn__filtr">Apply</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="business__inner">
  <div class="business__el">
    <div class="main__business">
      <p id="main__passive" class="main__passive">&#x2661;</p>
      <p id="main__active" class="main__active">&#x2764;</p>
    </div>
    <img class="img__business__el" src="./img/forstore.png" alt="">
    <p class="business__info">Интернет-магазин для компании, предоставляющей цифровые услуги</p>
    <div class="buy__main">
      <div class="price__main">
        <div class="discount__main">
          <p class="discount">400$</p>
          <img class="discount__photo" src="./img/photoeditorsdk-export.png" alt="">
          <p class="-price">12.5%</p>
        </div>
        <p class="price">350$</p>
      </div>
      <button class="buy__webmarket">Купить</button>
    </div>
    <div class="logistic">
      <img class="img__logistic" src="./img/11443063-transformed.png" alt="">
      <p class="logistic__text">В наличии</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="business__el">
    <div class="main__business">
      <p id="main__passive1" class="main__passive">&#x2661;</p>
      <p id="main__active1" class="main__active">&#x2764;</p>
    </div>
    <img class="img__business__el" src="./img/forstore.png" alt="">
    <p class="business__info">Интернет-магазин для компании, предоставляющей цифровые услуги</p>
    <div class="buy__main">
      <div class="price__main">
        <div class="discount__main">
          <p class="discount">400$</p>
          <img class="discount__photo" src="./img/photoeditorsdk-export.png" alt="">
          <p class="-price">12.5%</p>
        </div>
        <p class="price">320$</p>
      </div>
      <button class="buy__webmarket">Купить</button>
    </div>
    <div class="logistic">
      <img class="img__logistic" src="./img/11443063-transformed.png" alt="">
      <p class="logistic__text">В наличии</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="business__el NextRow">
    <div class="main__business">
      <p id="main__passive2" class="main__passive">&#x2661;</p>
      <p id="main__active2" class="main__active">&#x2764;</p>
    </div>
    <img class="img__business__el" src="./img/forstore.png" alt="">
    <p class="business__info">Интернет-магазин для компании, предоставляющей цифровые услуги</p>
    <div class="buy__main">
      <div class="price__main">
        <div class="discount__main">
          <p class="discount">400$</p>
          <img class="discount__photo" src="./img/photoeditorsdk-export.png" alt="">
          <p class="-price">12.5%</p>
        </div>
        <p class="price">370$</p>
      </div>
      <button class="buy__webmarket">Купить</button>
    </div>
    <div class="logistic">
      <img class="img__logistic" src="./img/11443063-transformed.png" alt="">
      <p class="logistic__text">Нет в наличии</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!--
<script type="module" src="./business.mjs"></script>
-->
```

Comment: You have duplicate `id` attributes (an `id` must be unique within the document), you have at least one surplus `</div>` tag at the end of the document, you're missing the opening `<html>`, and `<body>` tags to match the closing tags at the end (and only the content of the `<body>` seems relevant to the question). Posting all - or "a lot* - of your CSS isn't convenient (for us), since it means we have to look through a lot of CSS that's likely irrelevant. We're happy to help, and enjoy doing so, but please restrict your code to only the (relevant, and valid) [mcve] code.